# Nuget restore in Docker fails on latest SDK (6.0) but works on specific version (6.0.201)

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

I have an existing project that is using a specific SDK tag (6.0.3) in the Dockerfile. It works fine, but when I tried updating it to use the floating 6.0 tag, or the latest 6.0.400 tag, it fails:

```
/app/src/redacted/redacted.csproj : error NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://redacted/repository/nuget/'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source. [/app/redacted.sln]
  Failed to restore /app/src/redacted.csproj (in 77 ms).
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'dependencies-build' failed to build : Build failed
```

Why are the HTTP warnings causing the build to fail on the 6.0 tag? I thought Nuget HTTP support was not going to be removed until a later version.

Comment: Is it your own Nuget package repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `TreatWarningsAsErrors` turned on then Nuget will promote these HTTP warnings to errors and exit with an error code.

The solution is to either:

1. Update the project to use HTTPS for connecting to the repository
2. Ignore the specific error by adding it to the `NoWarn` list.
3. Turn off `TreatWarningsAsErrors`

In that order of preference.

Bear in mind that `TreatWarningsAsErrors` (and `NoWarn`) may be in the `.csproj` file or may be in a common `Directory.Build.props` file.

Comment: That doesn’t answer your docker part of the question

Comment: The only Docker element is the Nuget behaviour change in SDK image tag 6.0.300 whereby HTTP Nuget links now generate a warning whereas before they did not. (I'm posting and answering a scenario I just encountered to help others.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another bandaid:

You could also leave `TreatWarningAsErrors` on, and slap `<NoWarn>NU1803</NoWarn>` in your item group .